# Is there any connection between “machination” and Machiavelli?

Tags: etymology, latin, italian

Is there any connection between the term *machination* and the writer Niccolò Machiavelli or is it just a coincidence that they are so similar?

It seems logical because aside from having similar spellings, the terms *Machiavellian* and *machination* both mean cleverly sneaky and shrewdly planning. However, my research has been inconclusive and I cannot find a reference that *machination* derives from the writer (or any first-usage dates for that matter). Here are the points for and against it:

- For an etymology:

  - Identical meanings
  - Similar spellings
  - First known usage of *machination* is 15th century which coincides nicely with Machiavelli’s lifetime (1469-1527) and spread of work
  - The term *Machiavellian* became popular in the 16th century, so it was not long after his death that people were know to start coining words in reference to him and his style
- For just a coincidence:

  - Cannot find any references to Machiavelli being the etymology
  - Some sources refer to a Latin root: machinatio

So is there any connection, are they cognates, or is it just a big amusing coincidence?

Comment: (Yes there are big and little coincidences. ☺)

Comment: _Machination_ is just another derivative of Greek _mēkhanē_ and Latin _machina_. _Machiavelli_ is a family name, which may have to do with machines, in fact; I don't know.

Comment: No. Not even a coincidence in a technical sense. NARQ.

Comment: http://www.houseofnames.com/machiavelli-family-crest "First found in 850, when Ugo Macchiavelli was Marquis of Tuscany." http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=machiavelli (latter requires login)

Comment: *Machia* Lt. seems to imply 'conflict'. *... the Puritans sense of self was a "self civil war," which he renames "Auto-Machia," because "it evokes both modern autonomy and medieval psychomania" * (psychomachia) ... *medieval psychomachia (absence of intellectualism/natural law and its replacement by voluntarism/nominalism)* http://dissertationitis.blogspot.in/2008/07/im-in-midst-of-sacvan-bercovitchs.html See also, http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Auto_machia_Or_the_Self_Conflict_of_a_Ch.html?id=fz0QMwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machiavelli_(famiglia) On the family emblem/coat of arms, there are nails which suggest that the family was either connected with smiths or merchants dealing with metal, another theory suggests that the nails and the large cross in the middle are the holy relics which the brothers Alberico e Uberto Machiavelli took (stole) from their adventures in the crusades. Originally the surname was [Malclavellus](http://www.significato.eu/cognome/MACHIAVELLI) a deviation of Malchiodo, the Italianized version of the Jewish surname Melki'or = *my king* or *my God*.

Comment: [Chiavello](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=chiavello) is an archaic Italian word for chiave *key* and chiodo *nail* (not fingernail!).

Comment: @Mari Isn't that page saying that it derives **either** from _Malclavellus_ (a Mediaeval Latin name whose further origin is not touched upon) **or** from a popular remaking of _Malchiodo_, one of the various Italicised versions of _Melki’or_; and not that _Malclavellus_ has anything to do with _Melki’or_? (In either case, of course, there is no link to _machina_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Malchiodo derives from *Melki’or* and it also suggests that Macchiavelli is a deviation of Malchiodo. *"Detto questo, quindi, la variante in Macchiavello si spiega come una corruzione o una forma più tipicamente popolare di Malchiodo"*. *Chiodo*--> *Chiavello*, see my second link, and yes, there's no direct connection with *machina* = *machine*

Comment: @Mari Yes, the _Malchiodo/Melki’or_ => _Machiavelli_ link is clear enough; it was the connection between _Malclavellus_ and _Malchiodo/Melki’or_ that I couldn't see anywhere. Your first comment made it seem like _Malclavellus_ was derived from _Malchiodo/Melki’or_, but as far as my Italian will take me, _Malclavellus_ and _Malchiodo_ are two separate, unrelated possible origins given on the page.

Comment: @Mari-Lou. I think the link you provided indicating the origin from 'mal clavellus' with clear reference to the family Coat of Arms is the most plausible among different assumptions. In any case a lot of interesting research is available from the notes and it appears clear that despite the similarities OP can see that the two words are unrelated!.

Comment: @Kris, how exactly is this NARQ‽ Just because the answer is obvious to you doesn’t make it an invalid question (if that were a legitimate reason to close questions, then 99% of questions would be expunged from the network). And yes, it is most definitely coincidental that they both sound the same and mean essentially the same thing if they are not actually connected.

Comment: @everybody else, I had not considered looking into the Machiavelli lineage and background. Very interesting information. Unfortunately it seems to be even less clear now and is turning into a bit of a chicken-and-egg scenario. I suppose it could be argued that *machination* derives from Latin for mechanical in that plots and plans are like clockwork, but I don’t see how the sneaky, conniving aspect would fit; that must come from the style of Machiavelli’s writings for which he is specifically renowned.

Comment: @Synetech No answer is obvious to me, else I'd have posted one. The question is based on speculation and hence a NARQ.

Comment: The question is based on facts: they mean practically the same thing, and they sound similar (most cognates sound similar for a reason). Besides, there is almost certainly a definitive answer, and therefore there must be a real question since there cannot be answers to questions that aren’t real. You even called it a question in your comment, so you certainly cannot claim it to not be real; at most you can say it is not good enough for you, not to your liking. That does not make it invalid or not interesting to others (it already has an up-vote), let alone myself.

Comment: I don’t understand the acrimony; it is a perfectly valid question that anybody would ask, and in fact, many people have asked identical questions of different words without getting so much animosity. The SE network *used* to be friendly, welcoming, and open-minded. ◔_◔

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, aside from the similarities in spelling, there there is no connection between machination and Machiavelli. Machination comes from the Latin root *machinat-*, which in turn came from the Greek *mekhos*: "contrivance". There is no convincing evidence to suggest that the name Machiavelli was derived from the word, or any of its roots or later derivatives.

Comment: `No, aside from the similarities in spelling, there there is no connection between machination and Machiavelli.` …other than the similarity in meaning?

Comment: Yes, meaning as well, but the point is it's coincidental, since they are derived from different roots.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was trying to find out, if there is a connection or it is just an amusing coincidence. I can live with that answer.

Comment: Yes, it is just an amusing coincidence. _Machiavelli_ doesn't mean anything by itself, it only came to take on the similar meaning later on when people began to use it as an adjective: _Machiavellian_. The fact that Machiavelli happened to be fond of machinating is simply coincidental. There is no evidence to suggest that one is derived from the other.

Answer (score 1):

No: *macchinazione*, i.e. the act of *macchinare*, was already used before 1348 (G. Villani), and *macchinagione* in 1310. Source: DELI, Dizionario etimologico della lingua italiana.

Answer (score 0):

The family name Machiavelli could derive from a profession originally ie stainer of fleeces or could be connected with metal works ie 'The surname Macchiavelli is derived from the Italian word malo, and from the Latin malus, which means dangerous and chiavella meaning nail or spike.'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).